# What's the OracleParameter.Size influence?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, data-access-layer, odp.net

When developing an app that uses ODP .NET in DAL it's very annoying always set the `Size` property of `OracleParameter`. For instance:

```
getSPTimeCommand.Parameters.Add("pStartTime", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output).size = 200;
```

Isn't was so ugly? Thinking about auto set the `Size` parameter of `OracleParameter` I thought about it influence on performance or memory consuming. What is that influence? What is your scenario for setting a `Size`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1010881):

> Specifies the maximum size, in bytes or characters, of the data
>   transmitted to or from the database. For PL/SQL Associative Array
>   Bind, Size specifies the maximum number of elements in PL/SQL
>   Associative Array.

In your case it is the maximum size of the varchar2 you're passing to the database.

Comment: I did read docs. The question is there the difference by setting this `Size` property to 200 or `In64.MaxValue`?

Comment: The adapter will figure out the length of a string by calling str.Length. If you specify it ahead of time, it's a little faster because the adapter skips inspecting the parameter before creating the buffer for data transfer.

Comment: If I don't specify the Size property it just throws an Oracle error pointing that char buffer is too small.

Comment: Actually my version odt v11 doesn't even complain about that. It simply truncates the string parameter and sends it along.

Comment: Could you please write exact version of your odp?

Comment: The ODAC is 11.2.0.3.0 but the ODP is 4.112.3.0.